# Android:Not able to write on textview of main activity when comming from different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, textview

I created a simple demo program in which there is start button.When i click on start button on  main (Home) screen "hi all" appended to Text view.It works fine, But when I change the activity from selecting action bar menu and if again come on the home screen by selecting the action bar home menu then it will not show the "hi all " Message when I click on the Start button.

```
package com.example.testdemo;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
private TextView logArea;
private TextView log;

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            log = new TextView(MainActivity.this); 
            log.append("Heollosdfsjdf" + "\n");
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            log.setLayoutParams(params);
            log.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout chat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_view);
            log.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            chat.addView(log); 
            setDefault();
    }
    public void setDefault(){
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_recording_button);        
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                            startWriting(v);
            }
            });     
    }   
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }       
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {                                     
                            case R.id.home:
                            goHome();
                            return true;                                        
                            case R.id.general_setting:
                            generalSetting();
                            return true;
                            case R.id.server_settings:
                            serverSetting();
                            return true;
                            case R.id.audio_settings:
                            audioSetting();
                            return true;
                            default:
                            break;
            }
            return true;
    }       
    private void goHome() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, home.class);
            startActivity(i);   
            finish();
    }
    private void generalSetting() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, general.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
    }

    private void audioSetting() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, audio.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
    }
    private void serverSetting() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, server.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
    } 


    public void startWriting(View view) { 
            logMessage("Hi all");
    }
    private void logMessage(String msg) {
            log.append(msg + "\n");
            final int scrollAmount = log.getLayout().getLineTop(log.getLineCount())- log.getHeight();
            if (scrollAmount > 0)
                            log.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
            else
                            log.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
    }
```

Comment: your code please..!!

Answer (score 0):

it's because you called 'finish' when you changed activities. calling the main activity again reloads its view to its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MetaSnarf's answer: For a deeper understanding of the "Android Task Stack" and saving of the current Activity state, you might want to take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html